# Increment default constructed int in the unordered map

Tags: c++

I have unordered map of counters, e.g:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> counters_;
```

Do i need to manually create a value before trying to increment it? Will the next line be considered undefined behavior?

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> counters_;

counters_["non_existing_key"] += 1;
```

Comment: The `[]` operator will always create a "default constructed" value if none exists. For integer types that means the value will be zero. So the code will work just as you hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at), you're creating a new value in the map if it didn't exist before.
Furthermore, the value new will be [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), so incrementing the value is well-defined.